# Wait effect end to load screen

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I've created an effect to flip my button.
When i click it, it must load another screen.
My problem is:
I want silverlight to wait until the end of the "flipping" to begin loading the new screen.

If its possible, i would like to do it without using code-behind. Preferably on XAML.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using a StoryBoard to accomplish this. If that is the case then you can subscribe to the [Completed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and change your page in the event handler.

Comment: Correct, but he did ask: "i would like to do it without using code-behind". Best let him down gently :)

Comment: @HiTechMagic i wrote "if its possible".

Comment: Shawn i'm working with MVVM, this is why i asked this way. I tried to adapt what you post but it didn't work. Maybe i'm doing it wrong.